# Adding text to Elapsed Time column but keeping it as a numerical value so its picked up as a data label on the graph

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am currently using the formula below to work out the value in the **Elapsed Time** column.

[image]

Result:

[image]

I have also formatted the cell to format the output in the following way **# days** where # is the number:

[image]

But I also want to add the text in the LOB column to the Elapsed Time column so it looks like this **TECHNOLOGY - 2 days**.

So that when it updates the graph, it includes **TECHNOLOGY - 2 days** label instead of just **2 days**. Currently when I try to add text manually, it fails to register it as a number anymore.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Maybe you could make use of hidden columns and hide the numeric value while showing the text value? That way, you still have it in your graph. If you want corresponding data labels though, I'm afraid you'll have to manually insert the text part.

Comment: This is a repost:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38bcdc04-d894-4076-b43a-f32324c297cb/adding-text-to-elapsed-time-column-but-keeping-it-as-a-numerical-value-so-its-picked-up-as-a-data?forum=exceldev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=[@LOB] & " - " & TEXT([@[End Time]]-[@[Start Time]],"0 days")
```

[image]

**UPD:**
You can use additional hidden column for graph values.

- use hidden column (for graph values) with formula: `[@[End Time]]-[@[Start Time]]`
- use column `Elapsed Time` for labels

[image]

For more information how to add *data labels* with text, see this link (section *"Add data labels"*): http://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/03/13/custom-data-labels-in-a-chart/

Comment: Will it appear on the graph as a label?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean? what data is used for your graph?